# Mirf not sending reply

Tags: rf, nrf24l01+

I am trying to create a server - node connection with NRF24L01+ chip and Mirf library with interrupts. It seem to work, but server does not seem to get reply from node. If I put it in the loop it receives. Can you check what is wrong with my code?
Server:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Mirf.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <MirfHardwareSpiDriver.h>

typedef struct{
  long int packet;
  byte address[5];
}
Test;
Test Toolkit;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Configuring NRF24L01+ module ...");
  Mirf.cePin = 9;
  Mirf.csnPin = 10;
  Mirf.spi = &MirfHardwareSpi;
  Mirf.init();
  Mirf.setRADDR((byte *)"clie1");
  Mirf.setTADDR((byte *)"serv1");
  Mirf.payload = sizeof(Test);
  Mirf.config();
  Serial.println("Configuring internal script variables ...");
  Serial.println("Setting system interrupts ...");
  Toolkit.packet = 9;
  attachInterrupt(0,wakeupFunction,FALLING);
}

void loop(){
  strcpy((char *)Toolkit.address,"CLI");
  Mirf.send((byte *)&Toolkit);
  while(Mirf.isSending()) { }
  //Mirf.setRADDR((byte *)"clie1");
  /*if(Mirf.dataReady()) {
    Mirf.getData((byte *)&Toolkit);

    Serial.println("Got data!");
    Serial.print("Packet number: ");
    Serial.println(Toolkit.packet);
  } else Serial.println("NO DATA");*/
  delay(1000);
} 
void wakeupFunction() {
  //while(Mirf.isSending()) { }
  if(Mirf.dataReady()) {
    Mirf.getData((byte *)&Toolkit);
    Toolkit.packet = random(300);
  }
}
```

and this is client

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Mirf.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <MirfHardwareSpiDriver.h>

typedef struct{
  long int packet;
  byte address[5];
}
Test;
Test Toolkit;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Mirf.cePin = 9;
  Mirf.csnPin = 10;
  Mirf.spi = &MirfHardwareSpi;
  Mirf.init();
  Mirf.setRADDR((byte *)"serv1");
  Mirf.setTADDR((byte *)"clie1");
  Mirf.payload = sizeof(Test);
  Mirf.config();
  Serial.println("Listening..."); 
}

void loop(){
  if(!Mirf.isSending() && Mirf.dataReady()){
    Serial.println("Got packet");
    Mirf.getData((byte *)&Toolkit);
    Serial.println("Packet number:");
    Serial.println(Toolkit.packet);
    Serial.println((char *)Toolkit.address);
    //Sending
    delay(50);
    Mirf.setTADDR((byte *)"clie1");
    Mirf.send((byte *)&Toolkit);
    while(Mirf.isSending()) Serial.println("Sending");
    Serial.println("Reply sent.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I suppose that function Mirf.dataReady() does not work properly in Server interrupt. I have the same problem.